# How to get <td> values that comes dynamically to table from angularjs scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I tried to get the  values from the table while loading so that based on data value I can set the  background color as an indication on my Dashboard. But am not to access the values can anyone help me.
Thank you.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
      <div id="content1" class="toggle" style="display:none">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="well">
            <table id="table1" class="table table-hover" ng-show="mytable1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Operational Analysis</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th ng-repeat="item in yearList">{{item.years}}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="operation in dataOperationList">
                            <td class="details-control"></td>
                            <td>{{operation.reportTypeDetail}}</td>
                            <td>{{operation.reportFormula}}</td>
                            <td>{{operation.reportRang}}</td>
                            <td>{{operation.year5}}</td>
                            <td>{{operation.year4}}</td>
                            <td>{{operation.year3}}</td>
                            <td>{{operation.year2}}</td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I tried by jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#table1 tbody tr").each(function() {
          // Within tr we find the last td child element and get content
          alert($(this).find("td:last-child").html());

    });
});
```

but it didnt work.

Comment: Don't mix jQuery and Angular like this. Let angular control the background color based on the same data that's already in its scope, instead of trying to read data back from the DOM.

Comment: okay but can u show me sample code how to set the background color according to my data #Daniel Beck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `ngClass` directive, it allows you to dynamically add CSS classes to an element. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

For example if you want to add a green background the a `td` element if it has 2019  as a content, first you should define a CSS class :

```
.green{ backgroud: green; }
```

Then, use the `ngClass` directive on the `td` element :

```
<td ng-class="{green: (operation.year2 == '2019')}">{{operation.year2}}</td>
```

Update :

You can also use `ngStyle` directive if want to get the color from a variable:

```
<td ng-style="{background: (operation.year2 == '2019')? colorValue : defaultColor}">{{operation.year2}}</td>
```

`colorValue` and `defaultColor` sould be defined somewhere.

Comment: okay but I do not want static color bcoz my values will be changing time to time

Comment: You can use ngStyle directive in this case, just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correction, you can test it here : https://jsfiddle.net/abec/6f47jepq/4/

HTML part :

```
<body ng-app="operationApp" onload="showTableValue()">
  <div class="row" ng-controller="operationController">
    <div id="content1" class="toggle" style="display:none">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="well">
          <table id="table1" class="table table-hover" ng-show="mytable1">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Operational Analysis</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th ng-repeat="item in yearList">{{item.years}}</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="operation in dataOperationList">
                <td class="details-control"></td>
                <td>{{operation.reportTypeDetail}}</td>
                <td>{{operation.reportFormula}}</td>
                <td>{{operation.reportRang}}</td>
                <td>{{operation.year5}}</td>
                <td>{{operation.year4}}</td>
                <td>{{operation.year3}}</td>
                <td>{{operation.year2}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function showTableValue() {
      var tbl = document.getElementById('table1');
      if (tbl != null) {
        for (var j = 1; j < tbl.rows[1].cells.length; j++)
          alert(tbl.rows[1].cells[j].innerHTML);
      }
    }

  </script>
</body>
```

JS part :

```
var module = angular.module("operationApp", []);

module.controller("operationController", function($scope) {
  $scope.mytable1 = true;
  $scope.yearList = [{
    "years": "2000,2001,2002,2003,2004"
  }]
  $scope.dataOperationList = [{
      "reportTypeDetail": "Report type details 1",
      "reportFormula": "Report Formula 1",
      "reportRang": "Report Rang 1",
      "year2": 1002,
      "year3": 1003,
      "year4": 1004,
      "year5": 1005
    },
    {
      "reportTypeDetail": "Report type details 2",
      "reportFormula": "Report Formula 2",
      "reportRang": "Report Rang 2",
      "year2": 2002,
      "year3": 2003,
      "year4": 2004,
      "year5": 2005
    }
  ];
});
```

Comment: Actually is required to be none so that when I click on <a> tag it will be displayed